# NHibernate: DetachedCriteria nesting more than once

Tags: nhibernate

I can't get DetachedCriteria to work properly after nesting more than once, the reason being that the DetatchedCriteria can only access aliased entities one layer higher.

The following doesn't work, for example:

```
var secondNestedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Baz>("baz")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("baz.FooName", "foo.Name") // Doesn't work
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("baz.BarName", "bar.Name");

var firstNestedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Bar>("bar")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("bar.FooName", "foo.Name")
    .Add(Subqueries.Exists(secondNestedCriteria);

var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>("foo")
    .Add(Subqueries.Exists(firstNestedCriteria)
    .List<Foo>();
```

Does anyone know a workaround that doesn't involve using HQL?

Answer (score 0):

I never had this problem, I usually use PropertyIn to join subqueries, but you can't always do the same.

In this particular case, you could fix it by using the property of the second query:

```
var secondNestedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Baz>("baz")
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("baz.FooName", "bar.FooName") // is equal to foo.Name
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("baz.BarName", "bar.Name");
```

If this doesn't help in your real case, you may ask for a solution of the real case. I don't think that there is a general solution.